# Navigation using jquery ui - drag and droppable: square into middle then execute

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to replicate the functionality found at the following: http://carbonstudio.co.uk
using jquery drag and drop.

Below you will find where I am upto at the moment.  The two issues I am initially facing is how do I go about changing what happens when you drag a list item into the navigation execute box so it changes to the company logo (or anything) then it will redirect off to a new page.

The second issue is I need to get these boxes to go around the navigation execute area like the above sample.

MY CODE AS IT CURRENTLY STANDS: http://jsfiddle.net/elogicmedia/GG5EL/7/

Thankyou

JS CODE (FROM JS FIDDLE)

```
$(function() {
// there's the gallery and the trash
var $gallery = $( "#gallery" ),
  $trash = $( "#trash" );

// let the gallery items be draggable
$( "li", $gallery ).draggable({
  cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
  revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
  containment: "document",
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "move"
});

// let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
$trash.droppable({
  accept: "#gallery > li",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    deleteImage( ui.draggable );
  }
});

// let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
$gallery.droppable({
  accept: "#trash li",
  activeClass: "custom-state-active",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    recycleImage( ui.draggable );
  }
});

// image deletion function
var recycle_icon = "<a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Recycle this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-refresh'>Recycle image</a>";
function deleteImage( $item ) {
  $item.fadeOut(function() {
    var $list = $( "ul", $trash ).length ?
      $( "ul", $trash ) :
      $( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" ).appendTo( $trash );

    $item.find( "a.ui-icon-trash" ).remove();
    $item.append( recycle_icon ).appendTo( $list ).fadeIn(function() {
      $item
        .animate({ width: "48px" })
        .find( "img" )
          .animate({ height: "36px" });
    });
  });
}

// image recycle function
function recycleImage( $item ) {
  $item.fadeOut(function() {
    $item
      .find( "a.ui-icon-refresh" )
        .remove()
      .end()
      .css( "width", "96px")
      .find( "li" )
        .css( "height", "96px" )
      .end()
      .appendTo( $gallery )
      .fadeIn();
  });
}


// resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
$( "ul.gallery > li" ).click(function( event ) {
  var $item = $( this ),
    $target = $( event.target );

  if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-trash" ) ) {
    deleteImage( $item );
  } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-zoomin" ) ) {
    viewLargerImage( $target );
  } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-refresh" ) ) {
    recycleImage( $item );
  }

  return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$trash.droppable({
  accept: "#gallery > li",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    deleteImage( ui.draggable );
    //add function here
  }
});
```

cant you just add another function call after the drop?

Comment: Thanks, why is it removing the h5 tag when it is dropped?

Comment: you need to modify the DeleteImage function, you need to animate the text and make it smaller to fit the smaller box